# Passing class type to generic method at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, runtime

I have an interface called IAuditable as follows:

```
public interface IAuditable
{
    string AuditSummary
    {
        get;
    }
    string AuditDetails
    {
        get;
    } 
}
```

And two generic method in AuditTrail class as follows:

```
public T GetActualOldValue<T>() where T : IAuditable
    {
        return FromXElement<T>(OldValue);
    }
    public T GetActualNewValue<T>() where T : IAuditable
    {
        return FromXElement<T>(NewValue);
    }
```

as well as i have one property to returning Audit Summary by getting a class **at run time** as follows:

```
 public string AuditSummary
    {
        get
        {
            if (HasNewValue || HasOldValue)
            {
                string libraryVal = GetLibraryValue();
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(libraryVal);
                foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
                {
                    if (type.IsClass == true)
                    {
                        if (type.FullName.EndsWith("." + ClassName))
                        {
                            /*Here i want to call GetActualNewValue<foundClass>().AuditSummary
                             * or GetActualOldValue<foundClass>().AuditSummary;
                             */
                        }
                   }
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
```

As you know we can find class at run time in specific library,
Please note i don't want to call a generic method at run time,just wanna call generic method with founded, in other words how can i pass a specific class to GetActualNewValue<...>() as T,

```
AuditTrail auditTrail = AuditTrail.GetAuditTrail(76);
string summmary = auditTrail.GetActualOldValue<DTClient>().AuditSummary;
string details = auditTrail.GetActualOldValue<DTClient>().AuditDetails;
```

This code work perfectly but the main problem is DTClient must find at run time and define as T for GetActualValue.

Thanks all.

Comment: Just so I understand, you're trying to iterate through types at runtime, place them into a variable, then use that variable as the type parameter on a generic method call?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    AuditTrail auditTrail = new AuditTrail();

    var method = auditTrail.GetType().GetMethod("GetActualOldValue");
    var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(auditTrail.GetType());
    var result = genericMethod.Invoke(auditTrail, null);
```

Comment: Your code just find a class at run time, As the code shows i have no problem with finding the class.

Comment: Sorry i haven't understood your problem in the first go., i have updated the code, please try again hopefully it will help

Comment: You're welcome, I've seen this solution before, Now how can i access to AuditSummary property from "result".

Comment: Your solution doesn't work because i must define Type as T while calling GetActualNewValue method,Anyway i don't want to invoke generic method at run time.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use static method passing old object and changed object in parameters to track changes.

```
public class
{
    AuditClass.AuditingUserActivity(OldObject,ChangedObject);   
}

class AuditClass
{
    public static void AuditingUserActivity<T>(this T obj1,obj2)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(); //Gets all properties exist in passed objects of both

        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
        {
            object value1 = typeof(T).GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(obj1, null); // gets value for each entity
            object value2 = typeof(T).GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(obj2, null);

            if (value1 != null && value2 != null)
            {
                //You can compare and check whether changes made or not
            }
        }
    }             
}
```